# Grab first URL off a Google search result

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula, google-search

I'm trying to use the following formula to retrieve the first URL off a Google search result, but I'm getting the error that `Imported content is empty.` :

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.google.com/search?q=cnn&num=1", "//cite")
```

It looks like the result URL is contained within an `cite` tag in the results page, but the formula isn't working as expected. I expected this formula would return `https://www.cnn.com`. Same formula with `//h3` as XPath does return the title.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think Google is blocking your request. Try `=IMPORTDATA()` to see if there's any response that's actually returned.

Comment: It is against Google's [Webmaster Guidelines](//developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/webmaster-guidelines) and [terms of service](//policies.google.com/terms/archive/20020906?hl=en) to submit programmatic search queries. Running this code against Google is likely to cause Google to show captcha for searches from your IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue:

The `cite` tag is generated dynamically via script, making it unreachable to formulas like `IMPORTXML`.

You can see that's the case if you [disable JavaScript](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/disable/) and refresh the page. You won't see that element anymore.

#### Workaround:

The URL is also available in a `div` that is sibling of the `h3` element containing the title. This element is not injected dynamically via script, so it can be accessed by `IMPORTXML`. Retrieve that instead:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.google.com/search?q=cnn&num=1", "//h3/following-sibling::div")
```

[image]

#### Related:

- [How to know if Google Sheets IMPORTDATA, IMPORTFEED, IMPORTHTML or IMPORTXML functions are able to get data from a resource hosted on a website?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/115664/how-to-know-if-google-sheets-importdata-importfeed-importhtml-or-importxml-fun)